# Java Edit Text with certain rules

Tags: java

I have to edit text with certain rules :

The repetitive letters in the same word will be reduced to single letter.

```
"Questions" instead of "QuestionssSsS"
```

More than one gaps between words will be reduced to a single space

```
"go to the cinema" instead of "go    to   the     cinema"
```

Single letter which separated from the word will be connect to the word

```
"first ten person" instead of "firs t ten person"
```

For example :

```
String s = "I am enouuugGh of an artis t to draw         freely upon my imagination. ImaginatioOO n is more importan t than      knowledge. KKkKkKnowledge is limited. Imagination encircles the wwWorl d.";
```

Expected output :

```
I am enough of an artist to draw freely upon my imagination. Imagination is more important than knowledge. Knowledge is limited. Imagination encircles the world.
```

Please give suggestions and advice.

Comment: Homework? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s = "I am enouuugGh of an artis t to draw         freely upon my imagination. ImaginatioOO n is more importan t than      knowledge. KKkKkKnowledge is limited. Imagination encircles the wwWorl d.";
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println("========================================================");
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");
s = s.replaceAll("(?i)(\\w)\\1+","$1");
s = s.replaceAll("(\\w+) (\\w)(?=[ \\.\\?!,])","$1$2");
System.out.println(s);
```

output : `I am enough of an artist to draw frely upon my imagination. Imagination is more important than knowledge. Knowledge is limited. Imagination encircles the world.`

```
 ==> \\s+ Several whitespace characters
 ==> \\w means A word character, short for [a-zA-Z_0-9]
 ==> \\w+ will represent one or more characters of \\w class
 we will also place it in group (\\w+) - this will be 2nd group
 ==> Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE flag is (?i)
 ==> $number is backreferrence
```

Comment: Maybe explain what you've done and why? It works, but it's not so easy to understand if you aren't familiar with regexes

Comment: Normally I would upvote this answer but OP clearly asked for `suggestions and advice` not working solution, probably want to do his homework himself but dont know where to start.

Comment: It is very complex for me :(

Comment: @Pshemo you are right.I am sorry .@user2742616 instead of this regexes you can use for loop for this question please try so far. If you can't I would help you .